How do generators of translations transform under the adjoint representation of the restricted Lorentz group?
Context
Consider the usual Poincaré algebra $\mathfrak{iso}(1,3)$ of the Poincaré group $\text{ISO}(1,3)$. For physical reasons, we focus on the restricted Poincaré group $\mathbb{R}^4 \rtimes SO^+(1,3)$, which has the same Lie algebra $\mathfrak{iso}(1,3)$. There are four generators of spacetime translation in $\mathfrak{iso}(1,3)$. I will organize them into a vector$^{[1]}$ $P^\mu$. I am trying to prove the (seemingly) standard result that
$$\Lambda P^\mu \Lambda^{-1} = \text{Ad}_\Lambda P^\mu = [\Lambda^{-1}]^\mu{}_\nu P^\nu$$
where presumably
$$\Lambda^{-1} = \exp(-c_iJ^i - d_iK^i).$$

My attempt
A posteriori in general, (and a priori at the least within a neighborhood of the identity), for all $\Lambda \in SO^+(1,3)$ $$\Lambda = \exp(c_iJ^i + d_iK^i).$$ By direct computation $$\begin{aligned} \Lambda P^\mu \Lambda^{-1} &= \text{Ad}_\Lambda P^\mu \\ &= \text{Ad}_{\exp(c_iJ^i+d_iK^i)} P^\mu \\ &= \exp(c_i\text{ad}_{J^i} + d_i\text{ad}_{K^i})P^\mu. \end{aligned}$$
By inspection of the Lorentz algebra, $\text{ad}_{J^i} P^\mu = c_\mu P^\mu$ and $\text{ad}_{K^i} P^\mu = c_\mu P^\mu$. Hence,
$$\Lambda P^\mu \Lambda^{-1} = M^\mu{}_\nu P^\nu.$$
If we define
$$[\Lambda^{-1}]^\mu{}_\nu:=M^\mu{}_\nu,$$
then we get an expression of the form
$$\Lambda P^\mu \Lambda^{-1}=[\Lambda^{-1}]^\mu{}_\nu P^\nu.$$
Is this the correct result? I think I have a misunderstanding because I expect $P^\mu$ to transform like
$$[\exp(-c_iJ^i - d_i K^i)]^\mu{}_\nu P^\nu,$$
which is distinct from what I computed above.

[1] Note that I am using "vector" in the mathematical sense. Not the silly physics nonsense sense.

Related/possible duplicate: this question and my answer there for the questionable use of the spacetime indices on the level of the abstract algebra and the relation between the adjoint action and the "transforms as a vector" claim.

I think your answer there brings some clarity. However, I am interested in showing the statement by means of "direct computation" as attempted in my question statement. @ACuriousMind

My answer uses "direct computation", just in terms of actually clear definitions...
